# How to make my debian to work as http/html proxy?

Tags: debian, proxy

I use debian on faculty server via putty having its public Ip adress. I have sudo. I wonder how to make it work as Http/html proxy for access to "web of science" from my home windows browser. I wonder where to get instructions on how to make my debian work as http proxy (if possible sequred)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Go to tunnels under "Connection > SSH > Tunnels" in the configuration menu

you would put the "-D9999" port number in the source port box and select the Dynamic option below. Then click add.

If it does not let you connect then you need to edit your "sshd_conf" file on your Linux box located at "/etc/ssh/sshd_conf".

The line you would need to change is:

```
#AllowTcpForwarding no

          too

AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

It might let you connect but not forward then check it out as well.

In firefox you have to make sure SOCKS v5 is selected with

"SOCKS Host: 127.0.0.1" "Port: 9999" set

and that you list "127.0.0.1, localhost" in the "no proxy for:" section

[image]

You also need to set up firefox to forward your dns traffic over the proxy or it will still rely on the local Internet or intra-net for dns lookup

in the url bar type about:config and press enter
click the I'll be careful button,
then search for the option "network.proxy.socks_remote_dns".
if the value says true than leave it alone but if not (it will in less you have changed it before) right click and select Toggle. Now everything should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

While `apt-cache search http proxy` gives some possible answers, I can't really tell whether there's anything worth recommending here. From my own experience, to make a secure tunnel it's best to use SSH and it's SOCKS proxy compliant dynamic port redirect.

```
$ ssh -D9999 you@yourmachine.net
```

This connect's you to your debian (you need SSH server enabled for that - `service ssh enable && service ssh restart` and allows you to use SSH, but also enables a SOCKS server on **your** (client) machine (port 9999). Now just go into browser and set your SOCKS address to 127.0.0.1 (or localhost) and port to 9999 - and you're set to go.

Comment: I already have ssh on it (only access I currently have to it is over ssh(putty)). I do not understand how to for example go to `url.com` using my debian as http proxy from my windows machine=( Could you please explain?

Comment: If you have connected through this command (including -D9999) you only have to set up your proxy settings on your browser. Once done, your browser will connect everywhere using this proxy by default.